# How to make easily use of XSDs located in a library?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, xsd

We decided to go for an plugin mechanism which brings some services / logic etc., we use XML as a model approach, so the plugin has to bring it's own XSD to be integrated into the XML of the main application. This is done like the Spring approach (e.g. util:, jee: and other namespaces).

We can't upload every plugins XSD to a server. The XSD is located in the JAR of our plugin. Is it possible without adding this JAR to an XML Catalog to directly access this XSD and be able to reference it? So Eclipse can find this XSD and perform the auto-completion, validation, etc.?

Short: We have an XSD in our library and want to make use of it, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the org.eclipse.wst.standard.schemas for examples of how to add schemas to the catalog from an Eclipse plug-in.